# Getting the maximum key value pair in a Scala map by value

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to pull the maximum value form a map along with its key.  For example:

`val map = Map('a' -> 100, 'b' -> 23, ... 'z' -> 56)`

Where 100 is the largest value, how would I go about pulling ('a',100)?  I essentially want to use Map.max but search by value rather than key.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `maxBy` with a function from the key-value pair to just the value:

```
val map = Map('a' -> 100, 'b' -> 23, 'z' -> 56)

map.maxBy(_._2)  // (a,100)
```

This is a short form for

```
map.maxBy { case (key, value) => value }
```

Comment: Perfect, that works! I do have to ask, where are you getting the syntax for the predicate passed to maxBy()?

Comment: If you look into the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Map), you find for `Map[A, B]`: `def maxBy[C](f: ((A, B)) ⇒ C)(implicit cmp: Ordering[C]): (A, B)` - the doc formatting is broken, I'm afraid, so I wrote the correct form here with a fresh type parameter `C`. So you pass a function from the tuple of (key, value) to any other value for which an ordering exists. `map.maxBy(_._2)` then is just the short form for `map.maxBy { case (key, value) => value }`.

Comment: Hi, what about if 100 is present for more than one key? Is it possible to get all values instead of just one? Thanks!

Comment: @Victor You'd determine the maximum value first and then filter the map; e.g. `val map = Map('a' -> 100, 'b' -> 23, 'z' -> 56, 'c' -> 100); val maxVal = map.valuesIterator.max; map.filter(_._2 == maxVal)`

Answer (score 3):

A slight modification in case the max value you are looking for is present more than once in the map:

```
// Find the entries with the max value in the map
val maxValue = map.maxBy(item => item._2)

// Filter the map and retain the entries with the max value
map.filter(item => item._2 == maxValue._2)
```