# New to Scala, better/idiomatic way than reduceLeft to find max (key,val) in collection?

Tags: scala

New-ish to Scala ... I am trying to find the best match from a collection of (key,value) pairs, where best match is defined as highest frequency. The method reduceLeft would be ideal, but the collection size may be smaller than 2 (1 or 0), so well-defined behavior for small collections is good.

Is there a more idiomatic scala approach to finding the max?
Other sources explained reduceLeft, which makes sense and reads well, but other approaches suggest different methods.

Is there a better way to extract the lone item from a collection of size=1?

Assume I have a map with some unknown number of values,
    m:Map[String,Int]

```
val vm = m.filterNot{ case (k,v) => k.equals("ignore") }
val size = vm.size

val best = if(size>1) {
  val list = vm.map{ case (k,v) => KeyCount(k,v) }
  list.reduceLeft( maxKey )
} else if(size == 1) {
  vm.toList(0)
  //another source has suggested vm.head as an alternative
} else {
  KeyCount("default",0)
}
```

Where KeyCount and maxKey are declared as,

```
case class KeyCount( key:String, count:Long ) {
  def max( a:KeyCount, z:KeyCount ) = { if( a.count>z.count) a else z; }
  def min( a:KeyCount, d2:KeyCount ) = { if( a.count<z.count) a else z; }
}

val maxKey = (x:KeyCount, y:KeyCount) => if( x.count > y.count ) x else y;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the maximum key value pair in a Scala map by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713118/getting-the-maximum-key-value-pair-in-a-scala-map-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduceLeft` works fine with lists of size 1. If `count` is always greater than 0 you can use `foldLeft` with the default case:

```
val list = vm.map{ case (k,v) => KeyCount(k,v) }
val best = list.foldLeft(KeyCount("default",0))(maxKey)
```

Otherwise simply use a condition with `maxBy` or `reduceLeft`:

```
val best = if(size>0) {
  val list = vm.map{ case (k,v) => KeyCount(k,v) }
  list.maxBy(_.count)
} else {
  KeyCount("default",0)
}
```

Note that you can use `maxBy` on the original `Map[String, Int]`, there is no need to convert the elements to `KeyCount`.