# Getting all key value pairs having the maximum value from a Scala map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have seen a similar post here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713118/getting-the-maximum-key-value-pair-in-a-scala-map-by-value/39713197) which is giving a single key-value pair which has maximum value in the entire Map.

But I would like to get List of pairs which has maximum value(maximum value is same for many pairs).

Ex : `Map(1 -> 7, 2 -> 1, 4 -> 7, 3 -> 2)`

Expected Output : `List(1 -> 7, 4 -> 7)`

This (`Map(1 -> 7, 2 -> 1, 4 -> 7, 3 -> 2).maxBy(x => x._2)`) will give only first occurrence `1 -> 7`

Comment: Thanks @vindev . That helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map.filter(_._2 == map.values.max)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
val maxValue = map.values.max
map.filter(_._2 == maxValue).toList
```